# Push Flexbox Off Canvas

Tags: css, layout, navigation, flexbox

Could you guys and gals help me figure out how I might push a flex column off canvas (essentially a negative margin or negative 3dtranslate) when a max width of say 60em is reached, that will result in the original flex4 content container to take up the full of the window?

The general html markup I am using is:

```
<body>
    <aside>
        Stuff
    </aside>
    <section class="content">
        Stuff
    </section>
</body>
```

I sincerely appreciate any help, I have really been racking my brain on this one. My end goal here will be to use the aside as a navigation bar coming from off canvas when at smaller resolutions.

[image: Starting Desktop View]

[image: End Result]

Comment: Max width of 60em meaning the width of which element?

Comment: Just on the body, so essentially.  @media(max-width: 60em){push the aside off canvas}     then     @media(max-width: 60em){Allow the Content (larger) module to take up the entire width}

Comment: Why does display:none not work, do you want the content still accessible when not shown?

Comment: With the aside gone the section will expand to cover the whole width if it has a `flex` property

Comment: I see, and that very well may be just what I need.  When I activate display flex, can I still animate it in from the left?  What I am going for is essentially this effect: http://codepen.io/banunn/full/KBtnD   with Flexbox

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer, is that more what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use media queries to set `display: none` on the aside when smaller than 60em: http://jsfiddle.net/3CZFx/
The aside will not be visible to screen readers etc when it is hidden with this. An accessible solution would be using `position: absolute;` http://jsfiddle.net/3CZFx/1/

Edit: or is this more what you're going for http://jsfiddle.net/3CZFx/2/

Comment: That is perfect! (The new fiddle). So is there no way for them to both be in flexbox? I just liked how flex could keep both the "aside" and the "section" elements the full height of the browser.   either way though, I'll take it!

Comment: They both are flexboxes and are the full height of the `.container`. The aside is just fixed width.

Comment: Works Perfectly! Thank you. I can't believe I didn't get to this on my own. Just overcomplicated things a bit.